# Urlencode & Urldecode in php

Tags: php, urlencode, urldecode

**On server**:

```
Browser Url--->http://www.mysite.com/?email=external%2Buser%40gmail.com

Email passed in browser--->external%2Buser%40gmail.com 

Email After Encode--->external%5Euser%40gmail.com /* using urlencode function */

Email After Decode--->external^user@gmail.com /* using urldecode function */
```

**On Localhost**:

```
Browser Url--->http://localhost/test.php?email=external%2Buser%40gmail.com

Email passed in browser--->external%2Buser%40gmail.com

Email After Encode--->external%2Buser%40gmail.com /* using urlencode function */

Email After Decode--->external+user@gmail.com /* using urldecode function */
```

In above code i don't know why server result is different than localhost. on server `%2B(+)` is converted into `%5E(^)` while `urlencode`. I want same result as localhost. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use `rawurldecode()` instead of `urldecode()` and `rawurlencode()` instead of `urlencode()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to the different character encoding on your `server` and `localhost`

Try converting them to a `common character set` as

```
urlencode( utf8_decode($strContent) );
```